# wordcloud error in R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I get this error when I try to plot wordcloud in Shiny app

```
"Warning in max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
  Warning: Error in strwidth: invalid 'cex' value"
```

Here is my code this code in server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(quanteda)
library(wordcloud)
require(readtext)

source('helperScript.R')


shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  output$prediction <- renderTable({
    result <- predicted()
    if(! is.null(result))
         p<- predicted()[,1]

  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    result <- predicted()
    wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)

    d <- data.frame(word = result[,1],freq= result[,2])
    wordcloud_rep(words= d$word,freq =d$freq, scale=c(4,0.5),
                  min.freq =1, max.words=50,
                  colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
  })

  predicted <- eventReactive(

    #execute with button "Go" clicked, nothing else
    input$go, {

      #Get Input from the UI
      inputTxt <- input$inputTxt

      words <- processInput(inputTxt)
      word1 <- words[1,]
      word2 <- words[2,]
      withProgress({
        setProgress(message = "Processing corpus...")
        predictNextWord(word1, word2)
      })

  })

})
```

Comment: sample of the data  NextWord freq
the 1
bed 2
sleep 3
a 4
school 5
work 6
my 7
church 8
this 9
college 10
hell 11
your 12
get 13
that 14
class 15
her 16
their 17
war 18

Comment: Sounds like you have missing values. Other answers to similar questions suggest things to look for include NA where there should be 0 or empty strings (""). Another answer suggested strings with length < 3 might be an issue.

Comment: Thanks @neilfws, Just to make sure I used data with strings length > 3                          NextWord
freq
1
have
40
2
see
37
3
help
24
4
hear
13
5
say
13
6
announce
12
7
share
12
8
report
11
9
take
8
10
give
6 and it's still the same, No NAs in this data or special char